# How to create an app where user can make his own tables on sqlite and kotlin

Tags: sqlite, android-studio, kotlin

Well... I don't know where to start with this... I'm doing a course where the teacher has not taught us anything about databases and now he want us to do an app with kotlin and sqlite where we make an Activity with a button "New table" where user can create a database table with a name and dynamic fields. I've been searching all day about it and I got nothing.

I thought about create a CRUD but I'm with the trouble that I don't know how to make any of this dynamically.

For now I have this SQLiteHelper that I saw it was necessary to make and I put const values to test it because I don't have any clue how to pass the values from the user view.

```
class AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(context: Context, name: String, factory: CursorFactory?, version: Int) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, name, factory, version) {

    companion object{
        const val DATABASE_NAME = "test.db"
        var TABLE_NAME = "Testing_Table"
        const val COL_1 = "ID"
        var COL_2 = "NAME"
        var COL_3 = "SURNAME"
        var COL_4 = "YEARS"
    }
    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
        db.execSQL("create table TABLE_NAME(COL_1 primary key autoincrement, COL_2 text, COL_3 text, COL_4 int)")
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists TABLE_NAME")
        onCreate(db)
    }
}
```

And I have this activity

```
class MainActivity2Crear : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2_crear)


        val buttonCrear = findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonCrear)
        buttonCrear.setOnClickListener{
            val register = ContentValues()
            register.put(COL_1, textView.getText().toString())
            TABLE_NAME = register.toString()
            val admin = AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this, TABLE_NAME, null, 1)
            val bd = admin.writableDatabase
            bd.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, register)
            bd.close()
            textView.setText("")
            Toast.makeText(this, "Table created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity2::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
        button.setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity2::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

I just did create button for now because I don't know what I'm doing...
I know probably this question will have downvotes but I just want some help or a tutorial or something that help me to understand how to make this exercise...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first issue that you will encounter is that you are trying to create a table using `CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME (COL_1 PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT .....`

The table that will be created (attempted) will be **TABLE_NAME** not **Testing_Table** as the variable name is embedded within the String rather than being resolved and appended to the string.

There are multiple inclusions of variables in Strings.

Another error is that you have `PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` autoincrement can only be used for an alias of the rowid which must be defined using specifically `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`.

You don't need AUTOINCREMENT as INTEGER PRIMARY KEY will do what you want (increment the value of the ID column so the first will be 1, then likely 2, then likely 3 ....). AUTOINCREMENT is basically a constraint/rule that says the number MUST be higher (for your testing it will be (not that it really matters)).

I'd suggest the following that is based upon your code (but without the click handling) that successfully creates the table, inserts some rows (not tables) in the table and then extracts them and writes the extracted data to the log.

First the modified **AdminSQLiteOpenHelper** :-

```
class AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(context: Context) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION) {

    companion object{
        const val DATABASE_NAME = "test.db"
        const val DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
        var TABLE_NAME = "Testing_Table"
        const val COL_1 = "ID"
        var COL_2 = "NAME"
        var COL_3 = "SURNAME"
        var COL_4 = "YEARS"
    }
    val db = this.writableDatabase //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED
    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {

        //<<<<<<<<<< NUMEROUS CHANGES >>>>>>>>>>
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME +
                "("
                + COL_1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," // no need for AUTOINCREMENT you want INTEGER PRIMARY KEY not PRIMARY KEY
                + COL_2 + " TEXT,"
                + COL_3 + " TEXT,"
                + COL_4 + " INTEGER" +
                ")"
        )
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + TABLE_NAME) //<<<<<<<<<<< CHANGED
        onCreate(db)
    }

    //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED >>>>>>>>>
    fun insertRow(name: String, surname: String, years: Int): Long {
        val cv = ContentValues()
        cv.put(COL_2,name)
        cv.put(COL_3,surname)
        cv.put(COL_4,years)
        return db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,cv);
    }

    //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED >>>>>>>>>
    fun getAllRowsFromTestingTable(): Cursor {
        return db.query(TABLE_NAME,null, null,null,null,null, COL_3)
    }
}
```

- please note the changes made in comparison to yours.

Now an Activity (MainActivity) that does the work of adding and extracting data from the database:-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Get an instance of the DB Helper with full class scope
        val db = AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this)

        // Add Some data
        db.insertRow("Fred","Bloggs",10)
        db.insertRow("Jane","Doe",25)
        // Get all the data as a Cursor
        val cursor = db.getAllRowsFromTestingTable()
        // traverse the cursor writing data to the log
        while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
            Log.d("MYDATA",
                "ID = " + cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(AdminSQLiteOpenHelper.COL_1)) +
                        " First Name = " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(AdminSQLiteOpenHelper.COL_2)) +
                        " Surname = " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(AdminSQLiteOpenHelper.COL_3)) +
                        " Years = " + cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(AdminSQLiteOpenHelper.COL_4))
            )
        }
        cursor.close() //<<<<<<<<<< should ALWAYS close cursor when done
    }
}
```

When run it produces the following in the LOG :-

```
2021-04-09 17:03:01.531 D/MYDATA: ID = 1 First Name = Fred Surname = Bloggs Years = 10
2021-04-09 17:03:01.531 D/MYDATA: ID = 2 First Name = Jane Surname = Doe Years = 25
```

**Additional**

Here's a revised **MainActivity** that has a button and will add a row to the table when it is clicked.

- The rows are all the same with the exception of the years value, it being randomly generated.
- After inserting the contents of the database are written to the log.
- No changes to **AdminSQLiteOpenHelper**

:-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Get an instance of the DB Helper with full class scope
        val db = AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this)
        val buttonCrear = this.findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonCrear)
        buttonCrear.setOnClickListener{
            db.insertRow("Button","Click", Random.nextInt(10,9999))
            logData(db)
        }

        // Add Some data
        db.insertRow("Fred","Bloggs",10)
        db.insertRow("Jane","Doe",25)
        // Get all the data as a Cursor
        logData(db)
    }

    // Function replaces the previous logging of the data 
    fun logData(db: AdminSQLiteOpenHelper) {
        val cursor = db.getAllRowsFromTestingTable()
        while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
            Log.d("MYDATA",
                    "ID = " + cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(AdminSQLiteOpenHelper.COL_1)) +
                            " First Name = " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(AdminSQLiteOpenHelper.COL_2)) +
                            " Surname = " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(AdminSQLiteOpenHelper.COL_3)) +
                            " Years = " + cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(AdminSQLiteOpenHelper.COL_4))
            )
        }
        cursor.close() //<<<<<<<<<< should ALWAYS close cursor when done
    }
}
```

Here's an example of the Log after clicking the button a few times :-

***Before any Clicks***

```
2021-04-09 18:45:47.813 D/MYDATA: ID = 1 First Name = Fred Surname = Bloggs Years = 10
2021-04-09 18:45:47.813 D/MYDATA: ID = 2 First Name = Jane Surname = Doe Years = 25
```

***After 1st Click***

```
2021-04-09 18:45:58.567 D/MYDATA: ID = 1 First Name = Fred Surname = Bloggs Years = 10
2021-04-09 18:45:58.567 D/MYDATA: ID = 3 First Name = Button Surname = Click Years = 9910
2021-04-09 18:45:58.567 D/MYDATA: ID = 2 First Name = Jane Surname = Doe Years = 25
```

***After 2nd Click***

```
2021-04-09 18:45:59.675 D/MYDATA: ID = 1 First Name = Fred Surname = Bloggs Years = 10
2021-04-09 18:45:59.675 D/MYDATA: ID = 3 First Name = Button Surname = Click Years = 9910
2021-04-09 18:45:59.675 D/MYDATA: ID = 4 First Name = Button Surname = Click Years = 8263
2021-04-09 18:45:59.676 D/MYDATA: ID = 2 First Name = Jane Surname = Doe Years = 25
```

***After 3rd Click***

```
2021-04-09 18:46:00.611 D/MYDATA: ID = 1 First Name = Fred Surname = Bloggs Years = 10
2021-04-09 18:46:00.611 D/MYDATA: ID = 3 First Name = Button Surname = Click Years = 9910
2021-04-09 18:46:00.611 D/MYDATA: ID = 4 First Name = Button Surname = Click Years = 8263
2021-04-09 18:46:00.612 D/MYDATA: ID = 5 First Name = Button Surname = Click Years = 9625
2021-04-09 18:46:00.613 D/MYDATA: ID = 2 First Name = Jane Surname = Doe Years = 25
```

Comment: SO MUCH THANK YOU for your time answering me... I will study your code to understand this better. It's so hard with this teacher to learn...